# Color text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

To be able to print in color from the terminal in python I understand that we can do something like

`text = '\x1b[94mtext to color\x1b[0m'`

so when calling the function

`print(text)`

print the text in color

Now, I made a dictionary to just choose a key and give me a random color, because I want to change the color of the text in a list, the problem is that it does not change the color, but it concatenates me just like the text, it is Say, instead of printing 'text' in color, it prints the string as is:

`'\x1b[94mcolor text\x1b[0m'`

I guess this has to do with the print() function that somehow already interprets the "\x" escape, how can I make it print it in color and not the text as it is? Thanks!

I attach code for anything

````
#colors pa distinguir un poco 
colors = {
    0 : '\033[0m', #color normal
    1 : '\033[93m', #amarillo
    2 : '\033[94m', #azul
    3 : '\033[95m',#morado
    4 : '\033[91m',#rojo
    5 : '\033[92m'}#verde


#para elegir uno al azahar
def color_azahar():
    """Elige un color al azahar de un diccionario de colors"""
    indice = random.randint(0, len(colors)-1)
    return colors[indice]

def pretty_print(arreglo):
    """Dado un arreglo de nxn imprime cada renglón para que se vea legible"""
    for i in range(len(arreglo)):
        print(arreglo[i])


def change(cuadri, n):
    
    if n == 1: 
        return cuadri
    if n == 2:       #  [[a, ]
        #caso donde        , ], 
        if cuadri[0][0] == 'a': 
            #sacamos el color 
            ado = color_azahar()+'a'+colors[0]
            #coloreamos los demás
            cuadri[0][1] = str(ado)
            cuadri[1][0] = ado
            cuadri[1][1] = ado
        return cuadri

prueba = [['a', ' '],['','']] 
pretty_print(change(prueba, 2)) # doesn't print color, it prints literally the text

text = color_azahar()+'a'+colors[0]
print(text) ```
````

Comment: When printing e. g. a list, the "repr"esentation of the items is printed (escape sequences are printed as they are). You have to write code to print the list items individually as strings.

Comment: Only strings can use escape characters

Comment: you may need `for`-loop and `"".join()` to convert it to string and print string.  ie. `for item in prueba: print("".join(item))`. If you try to print directly list, dict or other object then it will use `repr()` to create string useful for debuging - so it add `[ , ]` to list, it display all `\ `,  and display native chars as unicode, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's all just print statements, but using special codes that tell your console to start printing everything after this point in the new color.
You will need to reset if you want to go back and change it in previous lessons.

The somewhat random characters in the print argument are telling the computer to change the color of the next text output to whichever color you pick.

You must add the number from the table below.

**Color Value**
Default 0
Black   30
Red 31
Green   32
Yellow  33
Blue    34
Purple  35
Cyan    36
White   37

Example:
print("Uh, oh, you've been given a", "\033[31m", "warning", "\033[0m")

Comment: I forgot to mention-

You have to do it like this for all colors:
print("/033[{Text Color}m")

Note: the curly braces and the "Text Color" are not part of the command. They just show where to put the color's number value